# I am not get value which is sent in request body in specific json format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help in my one issue. I have write the program in that I am use map in node.js.

I am testing this program using postman by sending JSON structure, however I am not get specific value in console which I am printing.

Please see below code .

```
 async CreateProduceMVPRateAsset(data, callback) {
        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.

  var ProducePRICE = {};
             var MVPRATE = new Map();
             var MVPPRICE =[];
             var MVPPRICE_BS ={};
             var MVPPRICE_LB ={};

 var PRODUCENAME = data.PRODUCE
            console.log('PRODUCENAME', PRODUCENAME);

            var COUNTRY = data.COUNTRY;
            console.log('COUNTRY', COUNTRY);
            var STATE = data.STATE;
            console.log('STATE', STATE);
            MVPRATES =  data.MVPRATES;
             console.log('MVPRATERATE', MVPRATES); // not getting value of MVPRATES from request body

   }
```

JSON structure which is sending using POSTMAN

```
{
"username": "admin2",
  "PRODUCE": "Apple",
  "STATE": "MI",
  "COUNTRY": "US",
  "MVPRATES": {
    "fuji": {
      "VARIETY": "fuji",
      "RATE": [
        {
          "UNIT": "Bussel",
          "CURRENCY": "USD",
          "VALUE": 10.25,
          "UIDISPLAY": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "gala": {
      "VARIETY": "gala",
      "RATE": [
        {
          "UNIT": "Bussel",
          "CURRENCY": "USD",
          "VALUE": 10.25,
          "UIDISPLAY": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

output 
[image]

Any help very appreciable

Thanks
Abhijeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how logs will show up for the non-primitive type of data. Try stringifying the response like:

```
MVPRATES =  data.MVPRATES;
console.log('MVPRATERATE', JSON.stringify(MVPRATES));
```

This will help you in printing actual values to the logs. A better approach will be to use a logging module like [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) and configure all such things and many more.

Comment: thanks @Suresh Prajapati I also missed to intialize the variable

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste you all time I think I miss the var in front of MVPRATES. It should be
var MVPRATES =  data.MVPRATES;